# Hide/Show only specific categories in wp-admin new-post.php

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, wp-admin

Can anyone give me a function or an idea of the method I would need to use to hide categories from the selection box in wp-admin?

I have a custom post type and I would like my authors to be able to choose ONLY between 5 of those categories while they are editing their posts. I would like this to only be the case with the custom post type and NOT for regular posts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should do it. Replace `wpse_77670_getPermittedCategories()` with however you select the array of permitted categories, and `'your_custom_category'` with whatever your custom taxonomy is for your custom post type.

```
/**
* filter terms checklist args to restrict which categories a user can specify
* @param array $args arguments for function get_terms()
* @param array $taxonomies taxonomies to search
* @return array
*/
function wpse_77670_filterGetTermArgs($args, $taxonomies) {
    // check whether we're currently filtering selected taxonomy
    if (implode('', $taxonomies) == 'your_custom_category') {
        $cats = wpse_77670_getPermittedCategories();    // as an array

        if (empty($cats))
            $args['include'] = array(99999999);     // no available categories
        else
            $args['include'] = $cats;
    }

    return $args;
}

if (is_admin()) {
    add_filter('get_terms_args', 'wpse_77670_filterGetTermArgs', 10, 2);
}
```

Edit, to work with regular 'category' taxonomy on custom post type:

```
function wpse_77670_filterGetTermArgs($args, $taxonomies) {
    global $typenow;

    if ($typenow == 'tsv_userpost') {
        // check whether we're currently filtering selected taxonomy
        if (implode('', $taxonomies) == 'category') {
            $cats = array(89,90,91,92,93,94); // as an array

            if (empty($cats))
                $args['include'] = array(99999999); // no available categories
            else
                $args['include'] = $cats;
        }
    }

    return $args;
}

if (is_admin()) {
    add_filter('get_terms_args', 'wpse_77670_filterGetTermArgs', 10, 2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm a bit confused though on what to replace those two code snippets with. I tried using wp_list_categories to get the 5 ids of the cats and using the name of the post type (tsv_userpost) but it didn't work and just gave 404 errors on wp-admin.

Can you give me a little more explanation of what to put in those spots? Also, I'm not using a custom taxonomy for the categories. It is the same categories that I'm using for regular posts, I just only want to show 5 of them instead of all of them for the custom post type.

Comment: For the cat IDs, you can look them up in the admin; just hover over the category edit links and see what the term_id is. Then you can add them to an array: e.g. `$cats = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);`

Comment: I hate single-para comments! Anyway, for the category taxonomy: well, I guess you could add `global $typenow;` and test for `$typenow = 'tsv_userpost'` and use 'category' where I have 'your_custom_category'. Worth giving it a burl, I reckon!

Comment: OK, this is working:

 `function wpse_77670_filterGetTermArgs($args, $taxonomies) {

  global $typenow;
  if ($typenow == 'tsv_userpost') {
   // check whether we're currently filtering selected taxonomy
   if (implode('', $taxonomies) == 'category') {
    $cats = array(89,90,91,92,93,94);    // as an array

    if (empty($cats))
     $args['include'] = array(99999999);     // no available categories
    else
     $args['include'] = $cats;
   }
  
   return $args;
  }
 }

 if (is_admin()) {
  add_filter('get_terms_args', 'wpse_77670_filterGetTermArgs', 10, 2);
 }`

Comment: Grr, sorry for the crappy formatting. Anyway, this is working for limiting the categories on the user-post page BUT it's removing all categories from the normal posts edit page. Hmmmm....

Comment: The `return $args;` should be outside the `if` statement. I'll edit my answer to show what I mean.